# DocuSign API - "This User lacks sufficient permissions. Fail to resolve SendOnBehalfOf user" DocuSign Web API

Tags: docusignapi

We are allowing users who have created their accounts with DocuSign directly to connect to an integration we are providing.  As a result, we have no control over the account settings in place for each account created.

We are using the SOAP API and our header is comprised as the following.

```
r.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication",
              string.Format("<DocuSignCredentials><Username>{0}</Username><Password>{1}</Password>" +
                            "<IntegratorKey>{2}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>",
                            Email, Password, IntegratorKey));
```

On envelope creation everything works, however, on the following calls; **RequestRecipientToken**, **RequestUrlSenderToken**, and **GetAuthenticationToken** we are receiving the following error message, "This User lacks sufficient permissions. Fail to resolve SendOnBehalfOf user".

1. Do accounts created with DocuSign have the API rights enabled automatically? If not, how do you suggest we instruct them to enable them?
2. Is there a programmatic change we can make to avoid the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our implementation was correct but we were passing the wrong variables for that particular user.  The header listed in the question can be followed for future implementations.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the BehalfOfUser may be lacking the proper permissions.
The DocuSign user associated with the  element in your request must have the following permissions activated/checked in their DocuSign permission profile.  As an DocuSign administrator select Preferences > Users.  Find the send on behalf of user.  Open their profile and check the permissions associated to them.

1) Within the Sending and Signing section, check 'Send Envelopes'
2) Witin the DocuSign API section, check 'Sequential Signing (API)'

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The accounts we are integrating with are not administered by our company. The integration will be available for those individuals who already have a docusign account and would like to enable signing.  DocuSign asked us to use Free Developer accounts in the demo environment to test the integration.